# Is there ever a reason to have multiple bank accounts?

Tags: uplink

I always just use one bank account for everything, and I haven't noticed any problems. What good can multiple bank accounts be?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Bank accounts are useful for setting up bounces. If you create an account, obviously you *have* that account on the system, which makes the bank more valuable as a bounce node (dotted line around it; takes longer to process). Your log-in credentials will never be revoked, either.

You could of course hack an existing account, but creating one is much easier and does not start a trace, so this is useful early in the game.

Comment: Multiple bank accounts also allows you to have multiple loans. This can be useful if you are just short of buying something you need for your next mission.

Comment: @Nick The total loan is still limited to the same amount you get at a single bank

Comment: @Zommuter Ah, I was pretty sure I had used it to get multiple loans before. This was several years ago though. I'll have to recheck!

Answer (score 7):

Having a bank account will make stealing money from it much easier, as there is a very brief window of opportunity for you to delete the log of both sending and receiving money. Not having to connect to another bank to do that is very helpful.